# React Build Stylesheets and Js files sent as wrong MIME type after update

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, caching, browser

I have a React app and some static pages served with Node js. Whenever I make an update, build the production react app, and serve it, react roputes I have visited before that were not changed are shown as blank white page. It happens across different browsers. The error:

`The stylesheet https://cmas-sam.rchland.ibm.com/static/css/main.5c31f6e0.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”`

is thrown, along with similar warnings about the js files.

The server responds with "304 not modified" for these css and js files.

A force refresh (i.e. ctrl+f5 on windows) fixes the issue, until I make another update.

The server serves both the react app and a static web site using the pug templating engine. I experience no problems with the static site's files.

If it is relevant, my file structure is

`node_modules
backend
- public (for pug)
- views (for pug)
- routes (for pug)
- server.js
build (compiled react files)`

My server.js includes the lines

```
// for pug
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug")

const groups = require("./routes/groups");
const builds = require("./routes/builds");

app.use("/groups", groups);
app.use("/builds", builds);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// for react
app.use(express.static(`./build`));

app.get("*", authentication.isAuthenticated, (request, response) => {
    authentication
        .getAuthorizedUser(request)
        .then(user => {
            authentication.setTokenCookie(response, user);
            response.sendFile("index.html", {
                root: "./build/"
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("Routing: User not authorized");
            response.status(401).send("Not Authorized");
    });
});
```

Based on google searches, I believe the issue is on the server side. I have tried tweaks like using __dirname in the express.static() call and disabling etags, but have experienced the same issue.

How can I configure my server to correctly send the new modified versions of the react build files? Or force the client to pull them?